# Using realloc to extend memory space taken with malloc?

Tags: c

As a school assigment I need to create memory block with malloc and when its full it should extend itself with realloc.This will continue in a infnite loop.But I am getting segmantation fault error and I think the mistake is in realloc so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
  int boyut=5;
  int* dizi;
  dizi=(int *)malloc((boyut*sizeof(int)));
  int b=0;
while(b<1)  
    {   
if(*dizi<boyut){                
 scanf("%d",dizi);
dizi++;                
 }
else if(boyut=*dizi)         
 {
    printf("boyut yetersiz");
    dizi = (int*) realloc (dizi,2*sizeof(int));
    boyut=*dizi*2;                  
 }  
}
  return 0;
}
```

Edited according to answers its extending the malloc area by *2.

```
int main()
{
  int boyut=2;
  int* dizi;
  int* dizi1;
  int n;
  dizi=(int *)malloc((boyut*sizeof(int)));
  int b=0;
  int i;
while(b<1)  
    { 

if(i<boyut){           

  for(i=0;i<boyut;i++){ 
    printf("\nDeğer Girin:");
 scanf("%d",dizi);
 }
 }
else if(boyut=i)         
 {

    boyut=boyut*2; 
    printf("\nBoyut yetersiz yeni boyutu %d yapıyoruz",boyut);
    dizi1 = (int*) realloc (dizi,boyut*sizeof(int));
    dizi=dizi1;


 }

}
  return 0;
}
```

Correct answer thanks for those who have same questions can use it.

Comment: You do have a debugger? Use it, it will tell you *where* the crash is, let you examine and walk up the function call stack, and examine values of variables.

Comment: `*dizi` not initialize until scanf. and after `dizi++;` cannot realloc.

Comment: But I can take 5 integers at the beginnging the segmantation fault comes when relloc happens.

Comment: There are other problems. why compare `*dizi<boyut`, why assign `boyut=*dizi`, when stop input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually reallocate to *less* than before the reallocation. First you allocate space for `5` (`boyut`) integers, then you reallocate space for only *two* integers. You need to increase `boyut` and reallocate with that as a multiplier.

You also need to remember that `realloc` can fail, and in that case will set `dizi` to `NULL`, making you both dereference a `NULL` pointer and loose the original pointer so you can't free it.

Also, [don't cast the result of `malloc` (or `realloc` for that matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

---

The *real* problem, as pointed out by BLUEPIXY, is because of *undefined behavior*. For `realloc` to work it needs to be passed the *original* pointer. You no longer have it after you do `dizi++`.

Also, when you allocate memory, the contents is *uninitialized*, meaning it will contain seemingly random data. So doing `*dizi` before you initialize that data will also result in undefined behavior. You might want to use e.g. [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) instead.

Comment: I did what you say but still same error.Code modified I added the new code.

Comment: @BugraSezer Most likely it's because of `dizi1=dizi;`. I think you mean the opposite.

Comment: nope nothing changed I modified the code again please have a look.

Comment: @BugraSezer Read the comment by BLUEPIXY.

Comment: I read what BLUEPIXY said but cannot understand what he meant ?

Comment: So I removed my dizi++ but with if I do this I think it will keep writing on the same memory block over and over again so how can I make it go on a for statement ?

Comment: Oke the working code is above its extending the memory by *2 thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `realloc` is the total size of the allocation requested, not the amount by which it should grow. You should keep track of the size of the allocation:

```
size_t size = some_size;
void *ptr = malloc(some_size);
// check for errors

while (some_condition) {
    size += some_increment;
    void *newptr = realloc(size);
    // check for errors
    ptr = newptr;
}
```

Comment: You said the same thing the answer above but still same error code modified please look..